# Differences in explanation for this verse "Yato vā imāni bhutāni jāyante" which describe the parabrahman

Tags: vedas, upanishads, brahman

In few upanyasams by Srivaishnava scholars, on the question of what is Brahman, I have come across this verse from Taittirīya Upanishad -

> Yato vā imāni bhutāni jāyante; yena jātāni jivanti; yat prayantya-bhisamviśanti; tat vijijnāsasva; tat Brahmeti.

How does the explanation of this verse differ between advaita and visishtadvaita?

Comment: If you are asking for list from other samparadayas, then this question could be closed as too broad. Already 1 close vote being too broad!

Comment: @AkshayS I didn't ask for "the entire" list. I said "some other key verses". Besides, a person answering the question might stick to one or 2 sampradayic details. That will certainly not fall under "too broad".

Comment: How much is a "some"? Few, some etc., are subjective and not suitable to describe on a Q&A site.  What are key quotes is also subjective. So, this is likely to get closed as too broad or primarily opinion based. A user might quote two sampradayas. But still the quotes nor quotes are over neither the sampradayas. This gives rise to more and more incomplete answers. Such list questions are discouraged.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma And how much is "broad"? The word "key" is the qualifier that restricts broadness.

"But still the quotes nor quotes are over neither the sampradayas." - what does this mean?

Close the question if thats what needs to be done.

Comment: There are many such key quotes. It is a person's choice which he thinks they are important or key or best. Hence, they're not good to describe on a site like this. They should be very specific. I added "the quotes" twice by mistake. I mean even if a user limits answer to 2 or 3 sampradayas, the key quotes do not finish. They're still incomplete. There are many sampradayas in our religion. Even if a user quotes some verses from a sampradaya, there is scope of answering from sampradaya. ".**require too much guidance for you to answer in full**, or request answers to multiple questions." - broad.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma By that logic, every answer from a samparadaya perspective is incomplete, because the depth can be increased by another learned person. Anyway, I think we are unnecessarily devolving in to wordplay. I can find many such questions which invited a wall of text as answers, but it is not a good use of both of our energies and time to get in to a tussle on that. Like I said, if the community votes it out, so be it.

Comment: @Ambi your question can be improved actually. Close vote is done and is not reopened when question cannot and is not possible to improve. But yours can be improved!

Comment: @AkshayS Lol... Maybe that could have been the first comment. Looks like the impending weekend is making people shoot first and ask questions later. :D :D Let me think of some ingenious way to "narrow down". I can't come up with any right now.